# shifting down the UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView, and inside it is a UIView, and dynamic UITableViewCells.
The UIView is positioned in the top of the Table, and the cells come right below it.

My problem is, when I enlarge the UIView after a certain button press, it overlaps the cells below it. Due to the cells being dynamic, I am not sure how to access the cells and move their origin.y downwards.
Furthermore, if I have a lot of cells, I don't really want to be moving each cell one by one.

I tried looking to see if the UITableView has some kind of offset parameter for its cells, but didn't find anything of that sort.

Through the storyboard, when I enlarge the UIView inside the table, the cells automatically are pushed below it, but unfortunately when I enlarge the UIView programatically through the code (after the button press), the cells stay in their original place and don't move.

Here is an illustration to show what is happening:
[image]

My AutoLayout is turned off.

Comment: It would be easier to put this functionality into a custom cell, so that, your table only manages a collection of `UITableViewCell` objects. That way you can increase/decrease the height of your custom table view cell and the other cells should respond without having to write a bunch of code to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want your custom `UIView` to behave like a `UITableViewCell` by moving the cells up and down as it grows in height. So do just that. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` whose height can change dynamically and render that cell at the top (or wherever else you want it).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be putting a UIView inside a UITableView in the manner that you are doing. As I see it, there are two main approaches:

1) Add the `UIView` above the `UITableView`. You have mentioned no reason as to why it needs to be inside of it.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];

view.translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
tableView.translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:view];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"view" : view, @"tableView" : tableView};

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil viewDictionary:viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view][tableView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing metrics:nil viewDictionary:viewsDictionary];
```

2) Assuming the UIView absolutely needs to be inside the UITableView, the best way to do it is by using the contentOffset.

```
CGSize innerViewSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 200.0f);
UIView *innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, -innerViewSize.height, innerViewSize.width, innerViewSize.height)];
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain frame:self.view.bounds];
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, innerViewSize.height);
```

Then, whenever you need to increase the size of the inner view, you change it's y origin and increase the `contentOffset.y`.

Comment: Thanks Infinity, Ill try this.
The reason I needed the UIView inside, is that both the view and the cells in the table will scroll together.

Comment: The contentOffset didn't do the job. I think the contentInset is what you meant. I will go with Aaron's answer on this one as it seems most reasonable. Thank you and up vote.